# How can I create small random groups containing one unit each from five sets of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

I have five sets of data. I want to create small random groups containing one unit each from all five sets.

Thank you.

Comment: Use RAND() and obtain random number within possible numbers in each group. Then use INDIRECT() to obtain the value from this random cell in a group.

Comment: Show us what you already tried and where is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Place your five data sets in columns **A** through **E** starting in row #3.  In **A2** enter:

```
=COUNTA(A3:A9999)
```

and copy across.  In **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A3:A9999,RANDBETWEEN(1,A2))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Your sample set is **A1** through **E1**.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (example).

[image]

Range A1:E10 contains 5 different data sets, each have its own elements amount (holes not allowed).

Used formulas:

```
A11=COUNT(A1:A10)
A12=INT(RAND()*A11)+1
A13=INDIRECT("R"&A12&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

Drag A11:A13 left. Each sheet change or recalculation (press <kbd>F9</kbd>) will produce new random set in A13:E13.

The formulas may be collapsed to

```
A13=INDIRECT("R"&(INT(RAND()*COUNT(A1:A10))+1)&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

In such case rows 11 and 12 are not needed and can be cleared.